# Auto focus on input field in Ionic Angular App, while open search popup

Tags: ionic4, angular8

I was getting an issue regarding auto focus in Ionic 4 and Angular 8 App

While I was opening the search modal in app, I wanted to auto focus on search box

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#properties

Check out the auto focus property

Comment: I tried that already and not worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For that I found the solution

I have added reference element on Input field 
Ionic Code

```
<ion-input placeholder="Search for Products" #product_id></ion-input>
```

Search Modal Component Code

```
import { IonInput } from '@ionic/angular';
export class SearchModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('product_id', {static:true}) product_id:IonInput;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.product_id.setFocus();
    },500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Still works with Ionic 5, thanks !